# Upload and redirect page using multer

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multer, node-rest-client, multer-s3

I am having a problem to redirect the page after a successful file upload using `multer`. With the file upload i am also saving some text into the database. Here's my code.

Question :

When the file and the contents are saved in the DB how can I redirect the page to a new URL ?

I am currently using `res.redirect('product/item');` but nothing happens. I also tried using `res.render`, but the page did not redirect.

**`Multer` method to upload a file to `Amazon S3`**

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'nameofthebucket',
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();

            cb(null, {fieldName: 'file.fieldname' + '.' + ext});
        },
        filename: function(req,file,cb){
            var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
                           cb(null,   Date.now() + '.' + ext);
        },
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
                cb(null,   Date.now() + '.' + ext);
        }
    })
})


var upload = upload.array('fileup', 10);
```

**The code responsible to upload the file and the content**

```
router.post('/uploadfileandcontent',function(req,res,next){

    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
        } else {


            saveRecordsToDB(req, function(err,data){
                if (err) {

                    res.redirect('/errorpage');
                } else {
                    res. redirect('product/item');

                }

            });


        }

    });



});
```

**Function that saves records to DB and makes the callback**

```
function saveRecordsToDB (req, callback){

            var args = {
                data: {
                        "name" : req.body.name, //
                        "age" : req.body.age

                },

                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

            };


            // registering remote methods 
            client.registerMethod("postMethod", "http://url/uploadfileandcontent", "POST");

            var req =client.methods.postMethod(args, function (data, response) {


                callback(null, 'success?');

            });

            req.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('error');


            });
}
```

Note: I also made use of [NODE REST CLIENT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) to send http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Tell me if it doesn't.

```
router.post('/uploadfileandcontent', function(req,res,next){

    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('Error while uploading.');
        }

        saveRecordsToDB(req, function(err,data){ 
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              req.flash('error', { msg: 'Error while saving data.' }); // Flash message -> need to configure your template to show it
            } 

            // Saved to DB
            req.flash('success', { msg: 'Saved' });
            res.redirect('/product/item'); // go to this page

        });

    });


});
```

**UPDATE**
You will need to include `const flash = require('express-flash');` to use flash message. Then you can load it to your app like this: `app.use(flash());`. The `app` is `express` loaded like this: `const app = express();`.

In your HTML you will access it in an array. Example using **[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)**:

```
//success
if messages.success
    for success in messages.success
        div #{success.msg} // Saved 
//Error
if messages.errors
    for error in messages.errors
        div #{error.msg} // Error while saving data.
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Can you also tell me how can I retrieve the `msg` from the HTML page ?

Comment: Updated with more details